# error while converting a file.ui to file.py

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am converting a ui file "file.ui" to a Python file "file.py" on command prompt using the command pyuic4 but while doing this, the cmd is giving me this error: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid  Win32 application.

This is how i am doing it :
C:Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4> pyuic4 -x file.ui -o file.py

Can someone help me please?..

Comment: Try to get the right bit-version of your executables. Ask yourself: What bit version is your os, what bit version is python and what bit version is pyuic4. Try to get them all to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application` usually means that you're mixing 32 bit and 64 bit python and python modules.

The easiest answer would be to ensure all are 32 bit since some python modules do not have 64 bit versions.

To check 32 or 64 bit python:

```
~ % python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', '')
```

Comment: okay i did what you showed me and it says 32bit... i dont really get what the problem is....

Comment: is pyqt4 is 64bit version?